# kubernetes volume mount timeout

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, kubernetes-pod, aws-ebs

I am using PVC to attach the volume to one deployment for grafana, but it times out and container kept in creating stage.
**Storage class**

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: grafana-storagetest
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  iopsPerGB: "10"
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

**PVC**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: grafana-claimtest
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Block
  storageClassName: grafana-storagetest
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10G
```

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: grafana-proxytest_mapping
      prefix: /v1/anonymous/grafana-proxytest
      rewrite: /
      service: grafana-proxytest.grafana-proxytest:8080
      timeout_ms: 20000
      connect_timeout_ms: 20000
  labels:
    app: grafana-proxytest
  name: grafana-proxytest
  namespace: grafana-proxytest
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: grafana-proxytest
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "20"
  labels:
    version: v1
  name: grafana-proxytest-v1
  namespace: grafana-proxytest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana-proxytest
      version: v1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: grafana-proxytest
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        image: <aws_ecr>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: grafana-proxytest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
            name: grafanapdtest
        image: grafana/grafana:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: grafanatest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      volumes:
       - name: grafanapdtest
         persistentVolumeClaim: 
           claimName: grafana-claimtest
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

**Pod status**
`grafana-proxytest-v1-7cb5b6b6cf-z5zml   0/2     ContainerCreating   0          4m18s`

**Describe Pod**

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                                                      Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                                                      -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling        4m14s (x2 over 4m14s)  default-scheduler                                         pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 7 times)
  Normal   Scheduled               4m12s                  default-scheduler                                         Successfully assigned grafana-proxytest/grafana-proxytest-v1-7cb5b6b6cf-z5zml to ip-10-10-107-59.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  4m10s                  attachdetach-controller                                   AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-f8ad51be-74c5-11ea-8623-068411799338"
  Warning  FailedMount             2m9s                   kubelet, ip-10-10-107-59.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Unable to mount volumes for pod "grafana-proxytest-v1-7cb5b6b6cf-z5zml_grafana-proxytest(fcf38cab-74c5-11ea-8623-068411799338)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "grafana-proxytest"/"grafana-proxytest-v1-7cb5b6b6cf-z5zml". list of unmounted volumes=[grafanapdtest]. list of unattached volumes=[grafanapdtest default-token-pzxdk]
```

Expected result - The volume should be attached properly and the pod should be in running status.

I checked and the storage class, PVC, and PV are created.

**Edit 1**
Added the namespace into PVC as below, but still it fails:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: grafana-claimtest
  namespace: grafana-proxytest
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Block
  storageClassName: grafana-storagetest
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10G
```

Still getting below error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age    From                                                      Message
  ----     ------                  ----   ----                                                      -------
  Normal   Scheduled               2m18s  default-scheduler                                         Successfully assigned grafana-proxytest/grafana-proxytest-v1-7cb5b6b6cf-gpk4l to ip-10-10-107-59.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  2m16s  attachdetach-controller                                   AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-5bbc63a3-755f-11ea-920e-0a280935f44c"
  Warning  FailedMount             15s    kubelet, ip-10-10-107-59.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Unable to mount volumes for pod "grafana-proxytest-v1-7cb5b6b6cf-gpk4l_grafana-proxytest(62c50717-755f-11ea-8623-068411799338)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "grafana-proxytest"/"grafana-proxytest-v1-7cb5b6b6cf-gpk4l". list of unmounted volumes=[grafanapdtest]. list of unattached volumes=[grafanapdtest default-token-pzxdk]
```

One thing as per the above logs i says that attach succeeded for volume, but then it fails for mounting grafanapdtest, which I am not able to understand.
PVC details:

```
get pvc -n grafana-proxytest
NAME                STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS          AGE
grafana-claimtest   Bound    pvc-5bbc63a3-755f-11ea-920e-0a280935f44c   10Gi       RWO            grafana-storagetest   15m
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure, this might not be entirely correct. It might be with Security Groups. But could you please let us know what's that PV? Are you using NFS for that purpose or any other way?

Comment: I am using aws-ebs